# What's the name of this raised wooden box structure around a tree on the sidewalk?

Tags: identification, trees

What's the name of this wooden box around the tree on the sidewalk? Does it have any utility?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure about an official name, but for utility... Try to sit on it, during the summer ;-P (Watch out for dog territory).

Comment: Its purpose is to provide street seating...its not about the tree as such, and the box will have been built prior to the tree being planted, rather than being built up around an existing tree.

Comment: Possibly it is a duel purpose raised bed and city bench?

Comment: For cities that encourage dueling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name is *"tree seat"* or *"wrap-around tree bench"*.

Here are some additional examples of tree seats (wrap-around tree benches):

---

[image]

(photo credit: Moosejaw Woodworks)

---

[image]

(from [How To Build A Bench Around The Tree In Your Yard](http://myamazingthings.com/how-to-build-a-bench-around-the-tree-in-your-yard/2/))

---

[image]

(photo credit: STREETLIFE)

---

The utility in both private and public spaces is multifold: seating, resting, observing birds, sleeping, giving speeches, to name the few.

Comment: It's not a tree seat or bench; those are always built round a tree growing in the ground, whereas the image shows a box with soil in which the tree is planted, with extension pieces to create a street design feature and seating - its repeated down the street I imagine, since we can see the edges of more than one.