# What's the correct name for this raised tree bed?

Tags: identification, raised-beds

What's the correct name for this raised tree bed? This one was designed only for the tree. And it's not inside a garden, not even in a park, but at the corner of the street. Searching on Google I can find mostly raised garden beds that contain a tree and the flowers planted around them.

And what's the name of the raised beds used in the parks or on the street? Most of my search results are gardening raised beds.

[image: enter link description here]

[image: enter link description here]
<sub>(source: [esi.info](https://cms.esi.info/Media/productImages/crop/100477_1473774301173_PF.png))</sub>

Here are [similar structures in Madrid](http://www.fernandoalda.com/es/trabajos/arquitectura/517/plaza-de-santa-barbara-madrid).One of them:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the name of this raised wooden box structure around a tree on the sidewalk?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35979/whats-the-name-of-this-raised-wooden-box-structure-around-a-tree-on-the-sidewal)

Comment: @Sue - I think they are quite different questions, because the other one is a Tree Seat. This one is a Tree Isle (usually in the form of a raised bed), the seat is only an extra feature of the wide border that I haven't even noticed and therefore it is outside of the scope of this question. I'll add a photo with a Tree Isle with narrow border, to make the question more clear

Comment: Fructibus, did you try to add a new picture, and it's not here? I only ask because the text says to enter the link description, so it should link to a picture, but I don't see a picture. That could be my browser, or perhaps the picture was accidentally incorrectly loaded and can't be seen. That has happen to me! I look forward to seeing a new picture! (By the way, I upvoted the question even though I thought it looked like a duplicate. When it had the picture, it met the criteria I use when deciding my vote. If there are downvotes, they're not mine!)

Comment: The reason I thought it was a duplicate is because the accepted answer used both terms. Also there's a comment from you under @Bamboo's answer saying that it can also be used as a tree seat, and that links back to the other question. Also, this one asks for the identification for two things, so I got confused. Maybe I should have considered them related instead. Please don't take offense, I didn't mean any. Mine is also the only close vote, so the community doesn't agree with me, which is why we have a community! Of course no matter what, it's your question!

Comment: The image was missing because of me, I asked for the Wikipedia image to be renamed so the image URL is different now. [The old file name is redirected](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Barcelona_raised_tree_bed_2017_A.jpg), but the image URL is not. Really, don't worry about the error, it's absolutely fine. They also look similar and they both have the seating feature. It's a pity that the people become too touchy when their content is evaluated - that's probably more visible on Wikipedia though. Maybe it's a glitch in the human nature, hopefully someone will find the fix one day :)

Comment: I found images with tree isles without seat but they are not https, so I just added a link at the end of the question.

Comment: I took the liberty to add the image of one of Madrid ones. Image insertion on this site doesn't  work entirely well anymore. I had to resort to manually editing link in the text. Also, I had to download the image on my comp first. @Fructibus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most correct term is *tree isle*. "Isle" implies it is a raised structure. In [this Google search](https://www.google.rs/search?q=tree%20isle&num=50&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKtsSBvdDXAhVQIlAKHXX_BHsQ_AUICigB&biw=1855&bih=981), you can see more examples, including some unusual, like this:

[image]

Of course, some structures can be called both tree isles and tree seats,but I think this question pertains more to tree isles.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a raised bed with seating surround, meaning the slabs on top are wide enough for people to sit on, and it's built to a height that's reasonably comfortable for seating. They can be made of wood, but for long term situations where there's a tree in the middle, particularly on a street, they're more usually built of brick or stone, like this one. If it has a special name, I've never known an architect use one... but maybe there is.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realized that it can be used as a [tree seat](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/35979/whats-the-name-of-this-raised-wooden-box-structure-around-a-tree-on-the-sidewal)